# argument type lambda expression is not assignable to parameter type int error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have a `Major` model like this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string MajorName{ get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public System.DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
public string StudentId { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public int FacultyId { get; set; }
public int MajorId { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase ImgFile { get; set; }
```

So I have a method like this in my repository for the above model:

```
public Major FindMajorById(int id)
{
    return _dbcontext.Majors.Find(id);
}
```

In my view I passed the id and I need the name of major:

```
<td>
    @{
        EducationRepositor.MajorRepository objmajor=new MajorRepository();
     }
     @Html.DisplayFor(objmajor.FindMajorById(modelItem => int.Parse(item.MajorId)).MajorName)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Degree)
</td>
```

But I get error in my view in this line:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(objmajor.FindMajorById(modelItem => int.Parse(item.MajorId)).MajorName)
```

My error:

> argument type lambda expression is not assignable to parameter type int

Comment: Well yes  your `FindMajorById` method takes an `int`, and you're providing a lambda expression. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: I want to show the name of my major not ID,

Comment: So how can i pass the id of my major that is provided by lambda?

Comment: So change your method to take an expression, or change your calling of that method to pass an int ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `int.Parse(item.MajorId)` instead of

`modelItem => int.Parse(item.MajorId)`.

The error message you got is pretty clear, you tried to pass a lambda expression as a parameter in a method, which takes only one parameter of type int. So inside your `DisplayFor`
you have to use

`objmajor.FindMajorById(modelItem => int.Parse(item.MajorId)`.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you've basically got your lambda expression and your method call the wrong way round. You *may* want:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => objmajor.FindMajorById(int.Parse(modelItem.MajorId)).MajorName)
```

In other words, you're creating a lambda expression which takes a model item, parses its `MajorId` property, calls `FindMajorById`, and then uses the `MajorName` property of the result. That lambda expression is used as the argument to `DisplayFor`.

I'm not an MVC expert (by any means) so it's not clear how much benefit the lambda expression provides, however - whether you could actually just call the method directly.

Comment: This is highly plausible.

Answer (score 1):

`FindMajorByID` expects a `int` value, and you are passing it a lambda expression with `objmajor.FindMajorById(modelItem => int.Parse(item.MajorId)`.

I believe you need to pass it `MajorId` like:

```
objmajor.FindMajorById(int.Parse(item.MajorId))
```

Not really sure why you are doing a `int.Parse` since in your class `MajorId` is already declared as `int`. If your model is point to a different class, which has `MajorId` as string then use `int.Parse` otherwise you will get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

try the following instead:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => objmajor.FindMajorById(int.Parse(modelItem.MajorId)).MajorName)
```